# I want to unset the Session When User Press The Back Button

Tags: php

I have a form which have 9 Steps I have design in this steps using Sessions and Code Whole Form in Php Using Concatenate Method. But Now I am facing a problem i want to allow the user to go on previous step when he click the step back button.

When i am trying to code in on click event php return me unexpected if or unset error. I tried two methods which is written below

```
 // METHOD 1
 $form .= "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='".unset($_SESSION['m_id']); ."' id='back'>Back</button>";

// METHOD 2 
$form .= "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='".
 if(isset($_SESSION['m_type'])){
 unset($_SESSION['m_type']);
 }
."' id='back'>Back</button>";
```

I am creating this form in php that is why in the last i echo my form variable.

Comment: You cannot run PHP code in the browser, which it would appear you are trying to do. `onClick` in a HTML button will run `JavaScript` but not PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in PHP. You are writing php code like javascript. You have to use AJAX for it. Create one page where you can unset session when click on your button. The way you are trying to do it impossible.

Comment: Its means we send the unset session request into an other page

Comment: What we pass in on click event ??

Comment: You don't have to pass anything there. Just send request on that page using AJAX and when that page get request it will unset session. Or you can pass anything that you need. :)